# Why can't I deploy to Heroku in GitHub Action: `Command failed: git push heroku HEAD:refs/heads/main --force`?

Tags: git, heroku, deployment, github-actions

I am trying to learn deployment in GitHub Action. In my `.github/workflows/demo.yml` file in my repository in GitHub, I added the following job for deployment to Heroku, by copying and modifying from https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-heroku:

```
  Deploy-to-Heroku:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # install Heroku: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-heroku
      - uses: akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.12.12 # This is the action
        with:
          # first in Heroku online account: account -> Account Settings -> API Key. copy it.
          # then in your project's repository on GitHub, Settings -> Secrets -> actions -> New repository secret: Then enter HEROKU_API_KEY as the name and paste the copied API Key as the value.
          heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
          heroku_app_name: "test-github-action-123abc" #Must be unique in Heroku. letters must be lower case, not upper case. c.f. error output
          heroku_email: "xxxx@xxxx.com"
```

I was wondering why the deployment fails:

```
Run akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.12.12
From https://github.com/xxx/testGithubAction
 * [new branch]      xxx-patch-1 -> origin/xxx-patch-1
Created and wrote to ~/.netrc
Successfully logged into heroku
 ›   Warning: Our terms of service have changed: 
Added git remote heroku
 ›   https://dashboard.heroku.com/terms-of-service
remote: Compressing source files... done.        
remote: Building source:        
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack        
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app        
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.        
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.        
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed        
remote: Verifying deploy...        
remote: 
remote: !Push rejected to test-github-action-123abc.        
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/test-github-action-123abc.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/test-github-action-123abc.git'
    Unable to push branch because the branch is behind the deployed branch. Using --force to deploy branch. 
    (If you want to avoid this, set dontuseforce to 1 in with: of .github/workflows/action.yml. 
    Specifically, the error was: Error: Command failed: git push heroku HEAD:refs/heads/main 
remote: Compressing source files... done.        
remote: Building source:        
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack        
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app        
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.        
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.        
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed        
remote: Verifying deploy...        
remote: 
remote: !Push rejected to test-github-action-123abc.        
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/test-github-action-123abc.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/test-github-action-123abc.git'
remote: Compressing source files... done.        
remote: Building source:        
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack        
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app        
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.        
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.        
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed        
remote:  !        
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 235b1971a13f659e7a3572c11caf9a1e4c2abce4        
remote:  !        
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 235b1971a13f659e7a3572c11caf9a1e4c2abce4        
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.        
remote:  !        
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:        
remote:  !        
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main        
remote:  !        
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:        
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...        
remote: 
remote: !Push rejected to test-github-action-123abc.        
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/test-github-action-123abc.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/test-github-action-123abc.git'
Error: Error: Command failed: git push heroku HEAD:refs/heads/main --force
remote: Compressing source files... done.        
remote: Building source:        
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack        
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app        
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.        
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.        
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed        
remote:  !        
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 235b1971a13f659e7a3572c11caf9a1e4c2abce4        
remote:  !        
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 235b1971a13f659e7a3572c11caf9a1e4c2abce4        
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.        
remote:  !        
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:        
remote:  !        
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main        
remote:  !        
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:        
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...        
remote: 
remote: !Push rejected to test-github-action-123abc.        
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/test-github-action-123abc.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/test-github-action-123abc.git'
```

Not sure if related, according to https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-heroku:

> To get started using the action, just make sure to have a Procfile or a Dockerfile in your project

I haven't understood Procfile, so haven't do anything about it. In particular, I don't know how to write Procfile for Python. My code in my repository is a simple Python scrypt with a test function:

```
#! /usr/env/bin python

# content of test_sample.py
def inc(x):
return x + 1


def test_answer():
assert inc(3) == 4
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Git issue, and not a GitHub issue.  This is a Heroku issue.

Whenever you use Git to start a Heroku deployment, *Heroku* takes the commit you'd like to deploy, and examines it for correctness.  All Git and/or GitHub have done here is *deliver the commit to Heroku*.

Heroku can produce information and/or errors at this point.  If and when it does so, it sends them *through* Git, which adds the word `remote:` in front of each information or error line:

```
remote: <something Heroku said to me>
```

In your case you are seeing:

> ```
> remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
> remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
> remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
> remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
>               to use for this application automatically.
> remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
> ```

(I broke up one long line for readability here.)

Note how Heroku is:

- telling you which Heroku stack it will use;
- telling you that its step for the Heroku-20 stack is now "determine buildpack";
- telling you that there's an error here: `!     No default language could be detected for this app.`

This error is followed by advice. **Read the advice.**  Go to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks and read the contents there, which tell you what to do next.

The subsequent errors are mostly due to this error, though eventually Heroku complains that you keep trying the same thing, which keeps failing, and that it's just going to keep failing until you try something different:  GitHub themselves are responsible for this try-again-several-times.  Read the GitHub output here:

> ```
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/test-github-action-123abc.git'
>    Unable to push branch because the branch is behind the deployed branch. Using --force to deploy branch. 
>    (If you want to avoid this, set dontuseforce to 1 in with: of .github/workflows/action.yml. 
>    Specifically, the error was: Error: Command failed: git push heroku HEAD:refs/heads/main
> ```

and decide whether you wish to modify your GitHub action accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Am I to read https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python and add requirements.txt and runtime.txt in my github repository? In the command `heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git`, how and where is the command 'heroku` installed? What is the command used for? Do I have to do something about Procfile?

Comment: I don't actually use Heroku. The `requirements.txt` file is standard for Python-y things; whether and how Heroku uses it directly, or creates it from a Procfile, or whatever it might do, I don't know. When using Heroku through GitHub you don't have to have Heroku installed locally, but I always like to be able to test from my own machine if possible, so if I were doing this I'd look into installing Heroku.